# apache mod_session in rewrite rules

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I would like to read the contents of the environment variable `HTTP_SESSION` created by `mod_session` and rewrite some urls depending on the user stored in it. But it seems I don't have access to it, even if I can see the contents in the CGI script.

I have a login form:

`cat /var/www/login/login.html`

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
    <form method="POST" action="">
        Username: <input type="text" name="httpd_username" value="" />
        Password: <input type="password" name="httpd_password" value="" />
        <input type="submit" name="login" value="Login" />
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

i created a testuser:

`htpasswd -c /etc/apache2/passwords testuser`

and the corresponding apache configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName simon.test
        DocumentRoot /var/www/

        RewriteEngine On

        LogLevel debug session:trace8 session_cookie:trace8 headers:trace8 rewrite:trace8

        Session On
        SessionCookieName session path=/;domain=simon.test;httponly;
        SessionEnv On

        <Location /login/>
                Require all granted
        </Location>

        <LocationMatch ^/(sp)/(.+)$>
                ErrorDocument 401 "/login/login.html"

                AuthType form
                AuthName "authenticationform"

                AuthFormProvider file
                AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/passwords

                AuthName "test"

                AddHandler cgi-script .sh
                Options +ExecCGI


                SessionEnv On

                RewriteRule .* - [E=test:thisworks]
                RewriteRule .* - [E=THE_SAVED_SESSION:%{ENV=HTTP_SESSION}]

                Require valid-user
        </LocationMatch>
</VirtualHost>
```

in `/var/www/sp/i.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Content-type: text/plain"
echo ""


env

exit 0
```

when i go to `http://simon.test/sp/i.sh` the login form is shown, and the login works, but the `THE_SAVED_SESSION` environment variable is never shown. Even in the apache rewrite debug logs it is empty, but the output of the CGI script shows its contents correctly.

Does someone know why, and how I can access the contents of that variable?

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule .* - [E=THE_SAVED_SESSION:%{LA-U:ENV:HTTP_SESSION}]
```

did the trick.